# Caffe lr_mult equivalent parameter in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, keras

I'm looking for the equivalent parameter `lr_mult` in Caffe prototxt file in Keras. I know we can freeze training using `trainable=False` in Keras, but what I'd like to do is not to set `lr_mult: 0.0` (learn nothing), but like `lr_mult: 0.1` (learn just a little bit) in some layers.